# Fire event onScroll using tinyscrollbar.js

Tags: jquery, scroll, tinyscrollbar

I would like to fire an event every time I scroll using tinyscrollbar. I've tried using jquery's scroll method but it only works on areas outside of the tinyscrollbar section. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the following events.

```
$("#scrollbar").on('mouseup', '.track', function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});

$("#scrollbar").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    console.log('mousewheel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, in tinyscrollbar.js  line 167 
"function wheel( event )"